# How can I pass the arrayList from adapter to new activity with intent in kotlin, android app?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am a new about making app. I want to pass the data from adapter to new activity with intent. I want to transfer PastNotesActivity, but it does not working.Because oldTitleName shows me the error: found String, Required editable. How can ı fix it ?

```
class NoteAdapter(private var titleText: ArrayList<String>, private var image: ArrayList<String>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<NoteAdapter.ViewHolder>() {


inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {


    val itemTitle : TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerTitleText)
    val itemImage : ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerImage)



    init {

        itemView.setOnClickListener { v: View ->


           // Toast.makeText(itemView.context,"You clicked on item # ${position + 1}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            val intent = Intent(itemView.context, PastNotesActivity::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("oldTitle", titleText[position])

            itemView.context.startActivity(intent)

        }

    }


}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {

    val v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.recycler_row, parent, false)
    return ViewHolder(v)

}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {

    holder.itemTitle.text = titleText[position]
    Picasso.get().load(image[position]).into(holder.itemImage)

}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {

    return titleText.size

}
```

}

This is PastNotesActivity, oldTitleName shows me the error: found String, Required editable. How can ı fix it ?

```
class PastNotesActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_past_notes)

    val intent = intent
    val oldTitleName = intent.getStringExtra("oldTitle")
    pastTitleText.text = oldTitleName


  val navBarTitle =   intent.getStringExtra("oldTitle")
    supportActionBar?.title = navBarTitle
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Lets say that you are passing the text of an item from your recyclerView to the textView of a desired activity.

Code this...

```
    val intent = Intent(itemView.context, PastNotesActivity::class.java)
    intent.putExtra("sampledText", "test123")
```

And code this in your desired activity...

```
    val textFromIntent = intent.getStringExtra("sampledText")
    textView.text = textFromintent
```

Comment: Btw, dont forget to check me if this comes out good for you.

Comment: it does not work, I editted the code again. I think, it is more clear now.